# training root cause analysis AI: question about dataset, state of the art

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

There are some companies like [Zebrium](https://www.zebrium.com/) around saying that they get an AI to do root cause analysis of logs. I think root cause analysis is essentially a multi-class classification problem. So I check for research on classifying logs but data sets and works I manager to find are all binary classifications (normal vs abnormal).

Program: https://github.com/wuyifan18/DeepLog
Dataset: https://github.com/logpai/loghub

Can anyone enlighten me by providing resources on multi-class (root cause analysis) rather than binary class (anomaly detection)? Many thanks.